# Pagenumber in the side margin

Tags: margins, page-numbering

Trying to recreate this style in latex

[image: https://i.imgur.com/XK8iIoU.png]

I want to know how/if it's possible to put the page numbers in the side margins? I've looked through fancyhdr, but it seems I can't access the margins (only the header/footer).

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example that shows what you've tried so far and which document class you're using?

Comment: I would have liked to include a MWE, but I had no idea how to approach it. What is the typical etiquette for that? I should have also mentioned I'm using the article class. Thanks @sergei-golovan for your answer which works nicely.

Comment: The typical etiquette is to provide at least something like `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fancyhdr}\usepackage{duckuments}\begin{document}\duckument\end{document}` (or instead of `duckuments` any other dummy content package). The most important part being the document class, since the best approach can heavily depend on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put arbitrary code into the `\fancyhead` definitions. Here is an example which puts page numbers approximately to the middle of outer margins (for the `book` document class).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
  \vbox to0pt{%
    \vskip0.5\headheight
    \vskip\headsep
    \vskip0.5\textheight
    \hbox to\textwidth{%
      \hskip\textwidth
      \hskip\marginparsep
      \thepage
      \hss
    }%
  \vss
  }%
}
\fancyhead[LE]{%
  \vbox to0pt{%
    \vskip0.5\headheight
    \vskip\headsep
    \vskip0.5\textheight
    \hbox to\textwidth{%
      \hss
      \thepage
      \hskip\textwidth
      \hskip\marginparsep
    }%
  \vss
  }%
}
\fancyfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]